# Log4j "fallback" appender

Tags: java, log4j

I am currently fine-tuning my log4j config of a relatively large project. Currently I have not yet configured the log-levels for all locations that could create log entries.

I would like to have log4j have some sort of fallback appender to log all messages for which no other appender has been configured. So if for example I have a log message to:

log to: a.b.c.d:WARN

and have an appender configured to log packages a.b.c with level INFO, then the output is logged to that appender.

If however I have no appender configured to handle a.b.c.d then the fallback should be used.

If I would have configured my a.b.c Appender to level FATAL, then nothing should be logged at all, as I deliberately configured log4j to leave these messages away.

I hope I was able to explain what I want to do :-)

Any suggestions?

Chris

Comment: Isn't this the default behaviour?

Comment: Hmmm ... well in my case I have the rootLogger logging everything the others are logging in one big log-file :-( Perhaps I'm configuring the rootLogger wrong.

Comment: If you don't want to get everything in the root logger, you can set the `additivity=false` flag on the other appenders, then the logs won't propagate. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Geee ... thanks for that :-) It seems to be as allways ... as long as you don't know the magic word you search without success :-( ... I would have accepted your answer, If I could ;-) ... so If you just suggest your "additivity" solution, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to get everything in you root logger, you can set the

```
additivity = "false"
```

on the other loggers. Then the logs won't propagate.

Comment: isn't it the opposite? "additivity" is set on logger, and then the appender setting won't propagate

Comment: You are probably right. Better to use `categories` I guess, since that is the term used in the log4j.xml file.

Comment: categories is the old obsoleted term.  It is now called "Logger".  Appender is another thing, I think you have mixed up Category/Logger with Appender

Comment: Ah, you live you learn. `Obsolete` is a strong word though, we still use it at my company. :) Corrected now.

Comment: Well, it is Log4J that declaring it is obsoleted  :) : http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html

Answer (score 0):

I think @Keppil seems mixing up something.

Additivity is something set on Logger, and it control how the settings of parent loggers (includes appender) propagate to the logger.

So, in OP's case, you may do something like this:

```
Root Logger -> Appender1
Logger a.b.c -> additivity = false, Appender2
```

By doing so, a.b.c (and all its children) will send its log to Appender2, while all other loggers will send to Appender1.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the additivity is _set_ on the logger, but affects which _appenders_ the logging is propagated to.

Comment: isn't that what I have been always speaking? :)

Comment: No, you wrote that it propagates to the logger in your answer.

Comment: I said the "SETTINGS (including APPENDERS) of parent logger is propagated".  I am talking about how appenders settings are carried from parent to child loggers, NOT about the flow of log events.